# How one can I request someone to join the game and then visible to other users?

Tags: iphone

I am asking this question as a small part of my question series regarding game programming. Refer [this question as the main one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131780/multiplayer-game-in-iphone-concept-strategy-design).

Now suppose I want to develop a game on iphone - a simple multiplayer board game. Suppose its a casino table and there is a table which is currently on (players are playing on) and someone wants to join the game how will one will request to join the game and then after acceptance of the moderator the user will be visible in the table and is "playing" in the table.

I don't know how connections work in online multiplayer iphone game.

You can provide me link, tutorials or to the point answers, anything will be great help for me and will be really appreciated.

thanks

Comment: I think there are two question in one. Also you could reformatted the text, so it is easier to read.

Comment: Two cut and paste questions with a terrible layout. @hib: you do this more often. Please format your questions and definitely don't add a newline to each line (why?), see: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Sorry guys for the incovenience @Martin , @Abel I have edited the question now

Comment: don't demotivate others from answering  .@Abel,@Martin

Comment: @hib, please read the FAQ, it might help: http://stackoverflow.com/faq. Don't worry about us demotivating others, we won't, we just help you *motivate* others. I'll help edit your question, because it doesn't seem that you understand what we meant and sometimes a little example is better.

Comment: ok thanks i will keep in mind next time .

Comment: The question sounds like you want someone to write the entire user management and network parts of your game. I've never made a game on the iphone, so maybe it really is that easy, but with C++ I'll have to laugh at you and tell you to learn how to program first. Do you even have part of your game working on the iphone?

Comment: @sims It is really unfair to judge people only looking at question .This is just concept clearing questions . I have not tell people to write code . I am just asking for showing the path

Comment: Well, hib, I don't know who you are. I can only read this question and think, "Darn, what a lazy guy." You said: "I don't know how connections work in online multiplayer iphone game." Do you even know how "connections" work on a computer?

Comment: @sims I don't think I should explain to you . whoever you are .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking for tutorials, so:
http://blogs.unity3d.com/2010/04/21/guess-whats-on-the-picture/

Considering that you need a server to coordinate this and maybe are looking for a framework:
http://exitgames.com/Photon